# Logical doubts in calculation inside gridview

Tags: c#

[image: Customized Gridview]

I got a gridview which shows in the above image. A small logical clarification need to be solved. I got 2 ranges 56-68 and 74-80. 56-68 should add in row 1(260,520,520) under 68 and 74-80 should add in row 1(260,260) under 80 and should give result in a next row(should create new row where row 2 becomes row 3) .

How could this be done??

Comment: Are you using WPF?
If so, you could create the exact entries you need in your ViewModel rather than trying to fiddle with the View. That is what the ViewModel is there for.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Its not MVC. Its just normal C# web application.

Comment: @VladButnaru: The code is half way. I am working on it. If you guys done like this already, pls share me the code...

Comment: please add the platform to your tags